# Does React Native offer an API for a Dialog?

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, react-native

I'm familiar with [React Native's Alert API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html), however, I'm looking for something more along the lines of what Instagram has. Is the following possible with the current version of React Native?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with [ActionSheetIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/actionsheetios.html).

For a cross platform solution check out [this](https://github.com/exponent/react-native-action-sheet) action sheet by Exponent.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think i got something for you :

1)[react-native-actionsheet](https://github.com/beefe/react-native-actionsheet)

2)[rnkit-alert-view](https://github.com/rnkit/rnkit-alert-view)

Cheers:)